# Tree height 1 more than right answer

Tags: java

I need to find the height a binary tree. I wrote the code and getting 1 more than what I am supposed to get.I don't know what is wrong with my method? What am I doing wrong?Here is my code:

```
 public int getHeight(Height node) {
            if (node == null) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                int lDepth = getHeight(node.left);
                int rDepth = getHeight(node.right);

                if (lDepth > rDepth) {
                    return (lDepth) + 1;
                } else {
                    return (rDepth) + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            treeHeight th = new treeHeight();
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int i, t, n;
            System.out.println("How many numbers you want to inout? ");
            t = sc.nextInt();
            for (i = 0; i < t; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter a number:");
                n = sc.nextInt();
                th.insert(th.root, n);
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
            th.display(th.root);
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("Height of the tree is : " + th.getHeight(th.root));

        }
```

Comment: _...getting 1 more than what I am supposed to get_ What are you supposed to get?

Comment: Debug your code please. We don't know what ``th.insert`` does and we don't know your input.

Comment: What I can see of your code looks ok to me, but do be aware that it measures tree height in units of *nodes*.  I prefer that myself, but some definitions of tree height instead measure in terms of *edges*.  Except for an empty tree, the height measured in nodes is one greater than the height measured in edges.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I am trying to solve this problem. For example , if I input 1 node, my answer should be 0. but I get 1  .https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-binary-search-trees?h_r=internal-search.

Comment: @MuhtasimAhmed then take a look at what the code does. Unless you pass ``null`` to the ``getHeight`` method, you're never gonna get ``0`` as a result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem defines the height of a tree this way:

> The height of a binary search tree is the number of edges between the tree's root and its furthest leaf.

Your approach counts nodes, not edges, and the height in nodes is always one greater than the height in edges, supposing that we exclude the empty graph from our definition of "tree".  Just subtract one from the result of the top-level invocation of `getHeight()` (but not from the results of its recursive invocations).

Comment: What do you mean by top level invocation ?

Comment: @MuhtasimAhmed, I mean the non-recursive invocation.  In other words, continue to compute the height in terms of nodes, and convert the result to units of edges (by subtracting one) when you need it in that form.

Comment: I still could not do it.

Comment: @MuhtasimAhmed, it's simple.  You already observed that your method produces a result that's too large by one.  I confirm that it does so systematically, and for good, understandable reason.  This fully answers the question you posed.  I go on to suggest that you address the problem by simply *subtracting* one at the end; I don't see why that's difficult to understand, given that it directly addresses the problem as you yourself characterized it.

Comment: If I subtract 1 , I get 0 for any input

Comment: public int getHeight(Height node) {
         int x;
        if (node == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            int lDepth = getHeight(node.left);
            int rDepth = getHeight(node.right);

            if (lDepth > rDepth) {
                x= (lDepth+ 1);
                
            } else {
                x= (rDepth + 1);
            }
        }
        return x-1;
    }

Comment: @MuhtasimAhmed, subtract one ***from the final result***.  I *explicitly* said *not* to perform that subtraction during the recursion.